# querying one collection value and send other collections values

Tags: node.js, mongodb

everyone, I have two Schema one is age and second are questions I trying to find the age from my age scheme and match with number of age 
and if age is true then it sends me the question from the second collection
But its loading... and displaying nothing

1). Node js

```
var agegroupQuiz = require('../models/agegroupSchema.js');
var questionQuiz = require('../models/question.js');


exports.agegroupController = function(req,res,next){


    try{

    var userObj = {};
    var projection1 = '-id age_group.age_group_5.max_age';
    var projection2 = '-id question';

       var a = agegroupQuiz.findOne(userObj,projection1); 
       var age = 'a.age_group.age_group_5.max_age';

       if(age===5){

        questionQuiz.find(userObj,projection2,function(err, data){
            if(err){
             console.log('getQuestions : Error while getting Questions ' + err);
             return next(err);
            }
             //console.log(question);
             res.send(question);
        });


       }else{console.log("error");}

    }catch(err){
        console.log('Error While Saving the reuslt ' +err);
        return next(err);
    }

 }
```

2). MongoDb Schema

```
 a). var mongoose = require('mongoose');

     module.exports = (function agegroup () {

     var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var agegroup = new Schema({

    age_group : {

    age_group_5: {

        _id:{type:String},
        max_age:{type:Number}
     }
    }
   });

   var results = mongoose.model('age', agegroup);

    return results;

    })();



  b). var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    module.exports = (function question () {

   var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

   var question = new Schema({

   question:{type:Array,

    _id:{type:Number},
    title:{type:String},
    options:{type:Array},
    result:{type:Array},
    feedback:{type:String}
    },
    metadata:{
        type:String,
        category:String,
        age_group:String,
        location:String
    }

   });

 var results = mongoose.model('userquestion', question);

 return results;

 })();
```

Comment: `console.log(a)` , i feel the query isnt executing.

Comment: is there any options to do this steps. If any, please share

Comment: just put `console.log(a);` beneath your `var a = agegroupQuiz.findOne(userObj,projection1);` and run the code again.  You can check the result in the terminal through which you are running your server.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I need to send the value of another collection name as the question to the browser as above I mentioned.

Comment: I think `projection1` and `projection2` should be `objects`, instead of just string. Something like this `{question:1}`.